# JWT (JSON Web token) front end webpack error

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, jwt, react-fullstack

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'

import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import Navbar from './Shared/navbar'



export default function Home() {

const navigate = useNavigate();
const [user, setUser ] = useState('')

async function populateUser() {

     const req = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/users', {
        headers: {
            'x-access-token': localStorage.getItem('token'),
        },
    })

    const data = await req.json()
    if (data.status === 'ok') {
        console.log(data)
    } else {
        alert(data.error)
    }
}


useEffect(() => {

    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    if (token) {
        const user = jwt.decode(token)
        if (!user) {
            localStorage.removeItem('token')
            navigate('/login')
        }
    } else {
        populateUser()
    }
}, [])
return (
    <>
    <Navbar/>
    </>
)}
```

I am trying to get user data in the front end by using jwt to decode the jwt token, however this breaks my app and I get this error [image]

I read online that this is a recent webpack issue (v5) is there a way to fix this? I am also not sure what the error message is asking me to do. To clarify without the jwt method I do get the token back and the login is successful.

Comment: I found you can use a library called jwt-decode https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it by using different package named jwt-decode. Here is the docs - https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode. It works!

Answer (score 6):

Install jwt-decode

```
npm i jwt-decode

import { jwtDecode } from 'jwt-decode'
```

Then

```
const decoded = jwtDecode(token)
console.log(decoded)
```

[Reference for jwt-decode npm and documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this issue, use any other jwt packages instead of jsonwebtoken. Or else use jwt-decode for particular decoding operations. Because React is a frontend library which doesn't have node compartments to comprehend jwt.
So that install jwt-decode in your frontend

```
npm i jwt-decode
```

after that import that to your particular page/component

```
import jwt from 'jwt-decode'
```

then decode the token as you did before.

```
const user = jwt.decode(token)
```

Dont destructure with different components. It is dedicated to work within your imported page/component.

Answer (score 0):

you can import just the `decode` from `jsonwebtoken` like this, I think this will help,

```js
import { decode } from "jsonwebtoken";

const secret = decode(params.userName);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the class I have created to mock as jwt.

```
import * as jose from "jose";
import { convertToMilliseconds } from "../Helper/convertToMillisecond";
const SECRET = process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_KEY;
const JWT_EXPIRY = convertToMilliseconds(process.env.JWT_EXPIRY || "24h");

class Jwt {
  async generateToken(payload) {
    try {
      const secret = new TextEncoder().encode(SECRET);
      const jwt = await new jose.SignJWT(payload)
        .setProtectedHeader({ alg: "HS256" })
        .setExpirationTime(new Date().getTime() + parseInt(JWT_EXPIRY))
        .sign(secret);
      return jwt;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
  async generateTokenWithExpiry(payload, expiry) {
    try {
      const expiryInMilliseconds = convertToMilliseconds(expiry);
      const secret = new TextEncoder().encode(SECRET);
      const jwt = await new jose.SignJWT(payload)
        .setProtectedHeader({ alg: "HS256" })
        .setExpirationTime(
          new Date().getTime() + parseInt(expiryInMilliseconds)
        )
        .sign(secret);
      return jwt;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
  async generateTokenWithExpiryAndNewSecret(payload, expiry, newSecret) {
    try {
      const secret = new TextEncoder().encode(newSecret);
      const jwt = await new jose.SignJWT(payload)
        .setProtectedHeader({ alg: "HS256" })
        .setExpirationTime(new Date().getTime() + expiry)
        .sign(secret);
      return jwt;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
  async decodeToken(token) {
    try {
      const jwt = jose.decodeJwt(token);
      return jwt;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
  async verifyToken(token) {
    try {
      const secret = new TextEncoder().encode(SECRET);
      return await jose.jwtVerify(token, secret);
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
}

export default new Jwt();
```

File ->../Helper/convertToMillisecond

```
export const convertToMilliseconds = (expiry) => {
  const expiryValue = parseInt(expiry.substring(0, expiry.length - 1));
  const expiryUnit = expiry.substring(expiry.length - 1);
  let expiryInMilliseconds = 0;
  switch (expiryUnit) {
    case "y":
      expiryInMilliseconds = expiryValue * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
      break;
    case "w":
      expiryInMilliseconds = expiryValue * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
      break;
    case "d":
      expiryInMilliseconds = expiryValue * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
      break;
    case "h":
      expiryInMilliseconds = expiryValue * 60 * 60 * 1000;
      break;
    case "m":
      expiryInMilliseconds = expiryValue * 60 * 1000;
      break;
    case "s":
      expiryInMilliseconds = expiryValue * 1000;
      break;
    default:
      expiryInMilliseconds = expiryValue;
      break;
  }
  return expiryInMilliseconds;
};
```