# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in node_modules\jwa

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am quite new to MERN stack, when I installed JsonWebToken it came up with 12 errors relating to 'webpack <5 used to include polyfills for node.js'. I've fixed all the errors but cant fix the cant resolve 'crypto' error.

My code is on github here: https://github.com/Morad17/mern-practice

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70467076/jwt-json-web-token-front-end-webpack-error/71089081#71089081